# Is there a way to debug react interactively

Tags: reactjs

I just wrote a react app now I'm hard time finding out what is going on. The error logs are not sufficient.

Error:

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, ref}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

I can't find anywhere in my code where I supplied an object as a component.

It also gives me a hint, the object has keys `{id, ref}`, but the issue is that I have multiple objects with those keys as well, maybe a full list of the keys would help.

Comment: Can you post your entire error message? It should contain a stack which may point you in the right direction.

Comment: This is a good argument for progressive development. That aside: there's somewhere in the code where a mistaken assumption has been made. It's difficult to know where to start looking w/o knowing anything about the code, code style, etc. but the offending component should be visible in the stack trace (or at least a root of it).

Comment: As I already said, the error log was insufficient,

Comment: The question you picked as a solution doesn't really match your question as titled.  Your question is how to find the root cause of this issue, not why it's happening.  We have several duplicate targets for the actual cause.  Trying to find what line of code (which is what your question as titled is) is much different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of error occurs when, you are trying to render an `Object`, like if you are trying to render a `file` having a structure

```
{
    name: string,
    size: number
}
```

and you directly render it as

```
<div>{file}</div>
```

it will lead to the error you are getting

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, ref}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

---

This can be rectified by doing it as

```
<div>{file.name} and {file.size}</div>
```

Comment: Your comment was really an eye opener

Comment: You can mark it as a Helpful Answer (green tick) as well to help others find it as a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to debug react interactively

Yes. To start, install React Dev Tools from your browser's store. This will get you a long ways in debugging.

You can also use tools like Web Storm to debug React.

Comment: I trued using react dev tools but it shows not. I'm using the "Components"

Comment: @Dave What do you mean "it shows not"?

Comment: It shows nothing

Comment: @Dave I still don't understand what you mean.